# check select statement is valid or not in c#.net

Tags: sql-server-2000

i want to check select statement(string) is valid or not in c#.net, if select statement is right then retrieve data and fill dropdown list box else drop down should be empty

Comment: This question is meaningless.

Comment: The more effort you put into your question, the greater both the quality of, and the quantity of, answers you'll get. This is unclear to say the least.

Comment: I removed most of the tags because they were incorrect or meaningless. Please explain yourself more and then someone can retag the question as appropriate.

Comment: The OP is looking for a way in C# to validate a SQL SELECT statement before firing it at the database I think.

Comment: Good question IMHO. I think it's a question that if you've been in that boat before, you can really appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

How often would the select statement be invalid?  Seems like a simple try/catch block around the execution of the SQL might be sufficient.

As an aside, I hope you aren't making an app that would allow someone to type in arbitrary SQL into a box which you would then execute...

Comment: There can be a situation where just executing the SQL and handling errors is not safe - suppose you are not fully in control of the SQL that's being executed. In this scenario, if the SQL is something very bad (say a TRUNCATE TABLE statement), then an error may not be thrown but it would have executed the malicious statement. Hence, I think it's safest in this scenario to follow the steps outlined in my answer.

Comment: @AdaTheDev - Exactly, which was why I had my comment about allowing someone to type in arbitrary SQL.  Very dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

One approach which covers most scenarios is to execute the SQL with `SET FMTONLY ON`

e.g.

```
SET FMTONLY ON;
SELECT SomeField FROM ExampleQuery
```

From BOL, [SET FMTONLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspxquery.1.) :

> Returns only metadata to the client.
>   Can be used to test the format of the
>   response without actually running the
>   query.query.

That will error if the query is invalid. You can also check the result to determine what the schema of the resultset that is returned would be (i.e. no schema = not a SELECT statement).

**Update:**
In general terms when dealing with SQL that you want to protect against SQL injection there are other things you should be thinking about:

1. Avoid dynamic sql (concatenating user-entered values into an SQL string to be executed). Use parameterised SQL instead.
2. Encapsulate the query as a nested query. e.g.

   SELECT * FROM (SELECT Something FROM ADynamicQueryThatsBeenGenerated) x

So if the query contains multiple commands, this would result in an error. i.e. this would result in an invalid query when encapsulated as a nested query:

```
SELECT SomethingFrom FROM MyTable;TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable
```

Comment: `SELECT SomethingFrom FROM MyTable);TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable;--`